# Swift: Getting 'Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered..' error when trying to open a URL in safari from my app

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

One of the specifications of my app is that on tapping a tableView cell, the user will be redirected to the website associated with the cell. Here is the code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: appdelegate.studentInfo[indexPath.row].url) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid URL", message: "Cannot open URL because it is invalid.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 
}
```

On my first tap, the URL opens like it is supposed to. However, returning to the app from Safari and touching another cell results in the following error, although the app still works like it is supposed to:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty
>   snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before
>   snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Is there any way to avoid this error? Or is this a bug?

I have experimented with dispatch_async blocks but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Based on so many answers, where this appears in numerous circumstances, it could be confusing to figure out which answer is relevant. The accepted answer has the right idea, but tailored to a specific case. The salient point of that answer is that `view.layoutIfNeeded()` at the right place and high-enough in the view hierarchy may solve it.  For example, it was occurring in my case for an arranged subview of a UIStackView in a custom UICollectionView cell. that one subview wasn't rendering for some reason and simply calling `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` solved it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It might not be the same problem as me, but I just solved the same warning in my logs.

I'm showing a `UIAlertController` as an actionSheet popover on an iPad, and I had exactly the same warning 8 times in a row every time I tried to show the alert controller.

To make the warning disappear all I had to do was to layout the alert controller view as in the following code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    ...            

alertController.view.layoutIfNeeded() //avoid Snapshotting error
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope this helps you or any other person having the same warning.

Comment: I'm using Objective-C and I see these errors when presenting a UIAlertController. If I do an [alert.view layoutIfNeeded] all the warnings go away but one. In other words, the repetition of this warning ends but I still see one in the log.

Comment: In Swift as of now i don't have any warnings anymore, i'll try to find some times to test it in Objective-C in my spare time, i'll let you know what i find

Comment: This brilliant answer solved my problem and removed ALL warnings. So I guess Hahnemann has another cause somewhere else for his last warning.

Comment: I just found that the last warning is caused by the title in the alert controller

Comment: Hu strange but good to know, i still didn't try it myself in objc, haven't had time yet. 

It might be that the title is in another view which isn't layouted when doing layoutIfNeeded, which would suggest it's in another hierarchy

Comment: The same fix worked for me when I'd presented a UIActivityViewController in Obj-C, then dismissed it and moved the app into the bg. Thank you.

Comment: Adding the layoutIfNeeded() fixes the same problem in Swift 4.  Thank you!

Comment: When the view in discussion is Keyboard but not the alertController, how do we handle that?

Comment: I honestly don't know, you could try to find the keyboard view by going through the hierarchy altough I don't recommend it, but just for the sake of testing it you could try to see if the warning gets removed. 

Maybe doing it on the textField you're editing could help.

Answer (score 4):

Also using Objective-C, using the suggested `[modeAlert.view layoutIfNeeded]` reduced errors to one as above. Final error has been suppressed by changing last addAction from `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` to `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` as below. Not a great workaround to what appears to be a bug.

```
[modeAlert addAction:[UIAlertAction
                  actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"")
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                  handler:nil ]];
```

Comment: I found that leaving off the Cancel option for the iPad sheet (it isn't shown for the iPad anyway) gets rid of the final error too.  I'm still bothered by having to call layoutIfNeeded, but my logs are now clean.

Comment: Adding "layoutIfNeeded()" got rid of error messages for me.  Swift:         alert.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Also discovered that I needed to do layoutIfNeeded() AFTER presentViewController(), rather than before - before seemed to work for iPad, but not iPhone.  Putting it after made things work for both types of devices.

Comment: @anorskdev same here - after seems to be the way to go.

Comment: iOS9 -- I left the style at cancel but did as suggested above -- to put the layoutIfNeeded AFTER the presentVC, and it cleared all messages.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the similar problem (same warning XD).

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

My Xcode version is **9.4.1**, and everything was perfect until I add `resignFirstResponder()` in `textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField)`.

---

## Here was my situation:

When I touched `UITextField` with **text** in the `UITableViewCell`, It will show the warning.

So I changed the way to trigger `UITextField`(**Edit version**). It never show the warning again.

In conclusion, I still don't know why this happened, but what I can do is avoid the warning, hope It will help someone :D

---

#### Edited code:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // add this in TableViewCell
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        answerTextField.isEnabled = selected
        if selected {
            answerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            answerTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Original code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let t = UITableView()
        t.separatorStyle = .none
        t.backgroundColor = .clear
        return t
    }()

    private let cellId = "Cell"

    private let data = [
        Model(title: "A", answer: "a"),
        Model(title: "B", answer: "b"),
        Model(title: "C", answer: nil),
        Model(title: "D", answer: nil)
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.frame = view.frame
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.section % 2 == 0 ? .gray : .white
            cell.setData(data[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let answerTextField = UITextField()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        setupTitleLabels()
    }

    func setData(_ data: Model) {
        titleLabel.text = data.title
        answerTextField.text = data.answer
    }

    private func setupTitleLabels() {
        answerTextField.delegate = self

        let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [titleLabel, answerTextField])
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.spacing = 0
        sv.distribution = .fill

        contentView.addSubview(sv)
        sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        sv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension TableViewCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}

struct Model {
    let title: String
    var answer: String?
    init(title: String, answer: String? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        self.answer = answer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid copy/paste from [Saliom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691050/9636) you can make such subclass and use it instead of `UIAlertController`:

```
class AlertController: UIAlertController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the last warning came from the Cancel button.

On iOS8 the cancel button is shown only when needed. If you run the app on iPhone it is visible. If you run the app on iPad the cancel button is not shown and the handler for the cancel action (style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel) is called when the user taps outside the popup.

the answer come from: [amalicka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32790760/4593553)

Answer (score 1):

I'm triggering a `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` `UIAlertController` after the user clicks a `UITableViewRowAction`, and I got the same error message repeated 8 times after presenting the `UIAlertController`.

On the iPad Pro Simulator for iOS 9.3, I tried [Saliom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691050/9636), and I went from eight log messages to one.

As [anorskdev suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685379/swift-getting-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-error-when-try#comment58319712_33943731), I put my call to `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]` after my `-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]` call, and all the warnings disappeared:

```
- (NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewRowAction *moreAction =
  [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault
                                     title:@"More"
                                   handler:^(UITableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action,
                                             NSIndexPath * _Nonnull moreIndexPath)
  {
    UIAlertController *alertController = 
    [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:name 
                                        message:nil
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
    UIAlertAction *deleteAlertAction = 
    [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                           handler:deleteAction];
    [alertController addAction:deleteAlertAction];

    UIAlertAction *cancelAlertAction = 
    [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             // totally ok to use the proper
                             // UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                           handler:cancelAction];
    [alertController addAction:cancelAlertAction];

    CGRect sourceRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:moreIndexPath];

    // You must specify a sourceRect and sourceView
    // or a barButtonItem or presenting a
    // UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet UIAlertController
    // will crash on iPad.
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sourceRect;
    alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.tableView;
    // first, present the alertController
    [self presentViewController:alertController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
    // then -layoutIfNeeded
    [alertController.view layoutIfNeeded];
  }
  return @[
          moreAction,
          ];
}
```

Notice that it wasn't necessary to use [Patrick's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33943731/9636) of using `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` for `cancelAlertAction` or [nurider's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912957/9636) of eliminating it altogether on iPads.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar debug warning when trying to present a QLPreviewController modally. I've read on other posts that it's an Xcode bug.

For me the error displayed when I ran my app on the simulator but not on an actual device. Must be an Xcode/Simulator issue. Hope that helps.

Comment: the answer that is already accepted seems better to me. Yours does not provide a real solution - one that avoids the error on both the device and the simulator.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and found a simple solution that makes sense.

If it's an iPad (`[UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`) then do **NOT** add the `UIAlertAction` with style `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` to the `UIAlertController`.

I made this change and my errors went away. This solution makes sense since you don't need a cancel action for alerts with style `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` on an iPad.

Comment: You're right.  This doesn't always solve the problem.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I think @Saliom's answer is the best.