# UIActionSheet - Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

So I have a `UITableView` inside a `splitViewController`. I have an `UIActionSheet` inside a `UITableViewCell`, if the cell contains a phone number, the `actionSheet` displays a list of options (Send Message, Add to Contacts, Copy). This is all working great when the iPad is in Portrait, but when tapping the cell in Landscape, I'm getting the following error:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

I have searched many SO posts regarding this issue, and they all seem to solve the issue if using an `UIImagePickerController` or `UIAlertViewController` - but none seem to get/solve the error when using `UIActionSheet`.

Here is my code:

```
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                                 delegate:self
                                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Send Message", @"Add to Contacts", @"Copy", nil];


        CGRect cellRect = cell.bounds;
        cellRect.size.width = cell.frame.size.width * 2;
        cellRect.origin.x = -(cell.frame.size.width / 2);

        [actionSheet showFromRect:cellRect inView:cell animated:YES];
```

I have also implemented `UIActionSheet` delegate methods to solve some other issues, so I'm wondering if I need to add some code to resolve the issues in the delegate methods?:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
    });

}

- (void)didPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{

}
```

Any help is much appreciated. This warning may not be serious, but I'm not sure if Apple will reject it due to the warning. The app doesn't crash or anything but still, I would like to get rid of the error. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for delaying the presentation until the next run loop?

Comment: I think that code was left over from previously attempting this functionality using a `UIPopoverController`. I will remove it now, good spot.

Comment: I think the problem lies in this line: `[actionSheet showFromRect:cellRect inView:cell animated:YES]` . You are presenting the actionSheet in the cell, while what you want to do is to present this in the root view of your viewController. Try changing `cell` to `self.view`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help - it just displays the `actionSheet` below the first cell in the `tableView`. I tried to change it to `cell.contentView` also but still the same warning message. I'm stumped, because it seems this should only appear if I'm using any camera functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue, but it goes even further as no action seems to work. It's worth noting that UIActionSheet has been deprecated in iOS 8, and it should be replaced with UIAlertController using a preferredStyle of .ActionSheet. I do get the same debug output when using UIAlertController, but at least my actions seem to work.

I can confirm, however, that with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685379/swift-getting-snapshotting-a-view-that-has-not-been-rendered-error-when-try), the debug message goes away.