# UIAlertController popoverPresentationController error: Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, uipopover

I have an `UIBarButtonItem` and that opens an popover like this:

```
@IBAction func openAdmin(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Elige una opción", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    // action button initializations... ... ...

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And when I open the popover with that function, I get this warning 4 times:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

What do I need to do to solve that warning?

I read a lot of questions with the same warning, but that questions was about the camera or a `UIImageView` involved, but I'm not using the camera neither a `UIImageView`. The popover it just have two `UIAlertAction`s

Answer (score 2):

You can find [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800747/1060971) to similar question in stack overflow.
All you have to do is to call layoutIfNeeded after presentViewController.

```
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
[alertController.view layoutIfNeeded];
```